# Make many rows to single using an index

Tags: r

According to this input:

```
structure(list(mid = c("text11", "text12", "text21", "text22", 
"text23"), term = c("test", "text", "section", "2", "sending"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

How is it possible to transform it using the mid to make the melt row to a single. where in mid the part text1, text2... text12 shows the number of row and the new number the terms exists in this row. Merging them with a with space separation.

Example out dataframe

```
data.frame(mid = c("text1", "text2"), term = c("test "text", "section 2 sending"
))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df <- structure(list(mid = c("text11", "text12", "text21", "text22", 
                       "text23"), term = c("test", "text", "section", "2", "sending"
                       )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

df %>% 
  mutate(mid = str_extract(mid, "text\\d")) %>% 
  group_by(mid) %>% 
  summarise(term = paste(term, collapse=" "))
# # A tibble: 2 x 2
#   mid   term             
#   <chr> <chr>            
# 1 text1 test text        
# 2 text2 section 2 sending
```

---

**EDIT** - to address comment

Addressing the question in the comment, the functions below will work for any case where all of the digits except the last one identify the group (i.e., 1 and 12 in the example below).

```
df <- structure(list(mid = c("text11", "text12", "text121", "text122",  "text123"), term = c("test", "text", "section", "2", "sending")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

df %>% 
  mutate(mid = str_sub(mid, 1, (nchar(mid)-1))) %>% 
  group_by(mid) %>% 
  summarise(term = paste(term, collapse=" "))

# # A tibble: 2 x 2
#   mid    term             
#   <chr>  <chr>            
# 1 text1  test text        
# 2 text12 section 2 sending
```

Comment: thank you. How about if you have this input `structure(list(mid = c("text11", "text12", "text121", "text122",  "text123"), term = c("test", "text", "section", "2", "sending")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))`

Comment: @demia I just edited the answer to deal with the question you posed in the comment.